# Instantiate generic based on property file setting

Tags: java, generics

I'm building a data driven test system.  I have done this before in XML but json is giving me some interesting issues.

For each request and response type json, I have a setting in my script where I specify a pojo type.  This type is instantiated to a class object thats passed to jackson to marshal the json into a usable pojo.  so its like this:

```
"responseType": "java.util.List",
```

eventually gets pumped to

```
Class<?> reponseType = null;
try {
    if (d.shouldPass) {
        reponseType = Class.forName(d.responseType);
    }
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    throw new RequestResponseTypeInvalid(testName);
}
```

and I have usable class info to use in jackson.  My problem is I need to do this:

```
"responseType": "java.util.List<foo>",
```

otherwise complex json types parse as hashmaps instead of pojo's.  I suppose I can get creative and put something in to go from hashmap to pojo if I need to but I was wondering if there was any straight forward way to do this.

I suppose another way is to implement a factory class where I could say list_foo in the property file and have the factory class map that to an actual class object.  That wouldn't be very hard but not as easy as just using the property.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in the way that you're hoping, I'm afraid. Generics are a compile-time thing only, and can't be used in this way at runtime, because of [type erasure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_erasure).

The best you could do would be to have some `list_foo` properties, and map these explicitly to `List<Foo>` and so in in your code. But you can't do it by reflection.

Comment: yea, I was afraid of that.  Oh well, I will create a factory.  Thanks